# fiware orion: configure by environment

Tags: fiware-orion

We are trying to deploy orion into kubernetes.

We're looking for a way to configure it using environment variables or a configuration file.

According documentation we're not quite figure out how to get since it seems that only we can set configuration using command line options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said and as far as I know the Orion container does not support env vars which makes things only a bit harder.

you need to create a K8s `ConfigMap` with all the Orion's configuration vars, ex.

```
kubectl create configmap orion-config --from-literal='MONGO_DATASTORE=mongo-db`
```

for instance the mongoDB datastore you are going to use.

then you need to fill in the env of the Orion container in the corresponding K8s `Deployment` from such a `ConfigMap` ex.

```
"envFrom": [
                            {
                                "configMapRef": {
                                    "name": "orion-config"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
```

and in the container command args you need to reference the `ConfigMap` properties through the `$(VAR)` syntax defined by K8s, example:

```
"args": [
                            "-dbhost",
                            "$(MONGO_DATASTORE)" ]
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Recently Orion has implemented env var support. You can have a look to [this section of the documentation about it](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html#configuration-using-environment-variables).

Currently this is implemented in master (so if you use Orion from dockerhub using `:latest` you would get it) and it will be available in the next Orion release (2.5.0).